# ASP.Net do asyncpostback from javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asynchronous, postback

I have a page with `UpdatePanel`. On the page there is Repeater control each repeater-item contains ASP.Net LinkButton and simple anchor HTML element.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="PerformFunc()" />click here</a>
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnFunc" runat="server" OnClick="Func" CommandName="Op" />
```

`UpdatePanel` is configured to `ChildrenAsTriggers="true"`. When I click on LinkButton everything works well: asynchronous postback goes and updates `UpdatePanel`.

What I need is:
In JavaScript `PerformFunc` function, bound to anchor element, run asynchronous postback of click on LinkButton. Or, simplifying: I want asynchronous postback of LinkButton click event to be run by clicking on HTML anchor element.

Tried lots of possibilities (javascript eval of href of LinkButton, javascript click method on LinkButton HTML element, registration of asyncpostback, that is actually unnecessary, because it is already registered). Any idea how is it possible to be done ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
function PerformFunc(){
    document.getElementById('<%= btnFunc.ClientID %>').click();
    return false;
}
```

You can trigger a click event in the link button using javascript.  Throw this in a function and call the function every time you want to do a partial postback.

edit: fixed server tag

You may also need to return false on the call.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="return PerformFunc();" />click here</a>
```